# How to plot lines between multiple nodes in 3D interface using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I want to plot the nodes like this figure, which are randomly deployed with uniform distribution in a three-dimension cubicle area with dimensions 10×10×10 mm. **How can I do this in Python?**

[image]

For more information: Here, (*)nodes will be referred to as destination nodes and (·)nodes as source nodes. The available communication link between two nodes is evaluated using specific ***SINRmin*** requirement and drawn with the dotted black line, which referred to as a segment. Here, the value of ***SINRmin*** is 8 dB.

Here is my code, what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 50

x1, x2 = 0.01, 0.1
y1, y2 = 0.01, 0.1    
z1, z2 = 0.01, 0.1

xs = (x2 - x1)*np.random.rand(n) + x1
ys = (y2 - y1)*np.random.rand(n) + y1
zs = (z2 - z1)*np.random.rand(n) + z1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "go")
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "k--")
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

My Output:

[image]

Comment: This post is unclear. Your question pertain to plotting within a range, which you succeeded, what are you specifically asking for? Plotting directional graphs? Have a look at FancyArrowPatch

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this code will demonstrate how to set marker's shape, marker's size, and line type. In the plot, `From Nodes` are in green dot shape, and `To Nodes` are in red star shape.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 50

x1, x2 = 0.01, 0.1
y1, y2 = 0.01, 0.1    
z1, z2 = 0.01, 0.1

# (origin) nodes
xs = (x2 - x1)*np.random.rand(n) + x1
ys = (y2 - y1)*np.random.rand(n) + y1
zs = (z2 - z1)*np.random.rand(n) + z1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
#ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "go")
#ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, "k--")
#ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, 'g.--', linewidth=0.8, markersize=8)
ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, 'g.', linewidth=0.8, markersize=8)

# (destination) nodes
x1,y1,z1 = 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
xs2 = (x2 - x1)*np.random.rand(n) + x1
ys2 = (y2 - y1)*np.random.rand(n) + y1
zs2 = (z2 - z1)*np.random.rand(n) + z1
#ax.plot(xs2, ys2, zs2, 'r*--', linewidth=0.8, markersize=8)
ax.plot(xs2, ys2, zs2, 'r*', linewidth=0.8, markersize=8)

#ax.plot(xs, ys, zs, color="k", marker=".")
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

# Plot line between (origin) from-nodes to (destination) to-nodes
# Assuming the lines apply in succeeding order between 2 groups of data
from_pts = []
for ea in np.stack((xs, ys, zs), axis=-1):
    from_pts.append(ea)

dest_pts = []
for ea2 in np.stack((xs2, ys2, zs2), axis=-1):
    dest_pts.append(ea2)

for from_to in zip(from_pts, dest_pts):
    #print("From:", from_to[0])
    #print("To:", from_to[1])
    ax.plot([from_to[0][0],from_to[1][0]], 
            [from_to[0][1],from_to[1][1]], 
            [from_to[0][2],from_to[1][2]], "b--", linewidth=0.6)
    pass

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: oplot]